Output of convolution of a shifted box function and an impulse response of low pass filter
I want to convolve this input:
Box delayed input function
with a low pass filter, with R is resistance in 2000 Ohm and capacitance in F is $1.5*10^{-8}$
And impulse response of the filter is
$$h(t) = \frac{1}{RC} . e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} . u(t)$$
This is my work:
Manual calculation
And my MATLAB code:
Ts=1e-6;

t = 0:Ts:0.01-Ts; N = length(t);

fs=1/Ts; F=fs/N;

f=(-fs/2):F:(fs/2)-F;

R = 2000; % Resistance

C = 1.5*10^(-8); % Capacitance (15 nF)

RC = R*C; % Time contant

h = (1/RC) .* exp(-t/RC) .* heaviside(t); % Impulse response of RC LPF

x2 = heaviside(t-0.002) - heaviside(t-0.0025); % box function

y2 = conv(h, x2)*Ts;

figure(3) % Plot result

subplot(2,1,2), plot(t, y2(1:N), 'Linewidth', 2.0)

axis([0 0.004 0 1.2])

xlabel('Time, sec', 'Fontsize', 14), ylabel('y_2(t)', 'Fontsize', 14)

grid on

And the result when i ran it:
Result of convolution
The graph itself seems correct but when substituting random values of t, the graph is incorrect. Am I missing something here? Maybe in hand calculation it shouldn't be -tau but I have to take into account the -0.00225 shift for tau too? That would create a big $e^{\frac{0.00225}{RC}}$ constant which I'm skeptical
Thank you
